# Magento admin filter by order_id can only filter 12 results max

Tags: magento, filter, grid, admin

I am trying to create a filter in the Magento Admin order grid. I have created a new class that extends the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid. I use the real_order_id column and filter_condition_callback to call a function that separates the input by ",".

The problem is that if I try to filter more than 12 items, it fails (going back to the homepage). Less than 12 is fine. I would like to filter a much larger amount of id's. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here the part of the column:
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

```
    $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'increment_id',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'separatedFilter')
    ));
```

Here the separate function

```
protected function separatedFilter($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    } else if(strpos($column->getFilter()->getValue(), ',') !== false) {
        //explode by comma, getting array of IDs
        $val = explode(",", $value);
        //filter the collection, where collection index (order_id) is present in $val array
        $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter($column->getData('index'), array('in' => $val));
    } else {
        //else use default grid filter functionality (like $value input)
        $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter($column->getData('index'), array('like' => '%'.$value.'%'));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Ok so I found out that this code works on a different server, with another installation of Magento. Does anyone have a suggestion that could lead to it working on the other server aswell?